# Why can only a person of the bloodline of Shannara use the sword?

Tags: shannara

So, I've been re-reading an old favorite, "The Sword of Shannara". In it, Allanon describes Bremen's mistake with who he gave the Sword to.

> Its power is potent only when it is believed, for it is power over the
>   mind which can neither be touched nor seen through human senses. If
>   the mind does not truly find some basis for belief in its existence,
>   then it can have no real effect. The Warlock Lord realizes this, and
>   the mind's fear of and belief in the unknownthe worlds, the creatures,
>   all the occurrences that cannot be understood by men's limited
>   senses-offer him more than enough basis upon which to practice the
>   mystic arts. He has been relying on this premise for over five hundred
>   years. In the same way, the Sword of Shannara cannot be an effective
>   weapon unless the one holding it believes in his power to use it. When
>   Bremen gave the sword to Jerle Shannara, he made the mistake of giving
>   it directly to a king and to the house of a king-he did not give it to
>   the people of the lands. As a result, through human misunderstanding
>   and historical misconception, the universal belief grew that the Sword
>   was the weapon of the Elven King alone and that only those descended
>   of his blood could take up the Sword against the Warlock Lord. So now,
>   unless it is held by a son of the House of Shannara, that person can
>   never fully believe in his right to use it. The ancient tradition that
>   only such a one can wield it will make all others doubtand there must
>   be no doubt, or it will not operate.

Now, my question is this: Given the mentality of the people, could Eventide not wield the Sword, seeing as he is the King of the Elves? The people believe that it is a weapon for Kings. So why can't Eventide use it?

EDIT

Allanon explains to the group that the power of the Sword is based upon the mentality of the people, that if they don't believe that they can wield it, then they will never unlock the true power. And it's not just the wielder. The people of the world have to believe in the wielder's ability as well.

Comment: Your quote makes it sound like anyone can use the Sword of Shannara.

Comment: I don't see how you could think that. The quote is stating that only those descended from Jerle Shannara can wield the Sword.

Comment: *through human misunderstanding and historical misconception, the universal belief grew* says to me that the requirement of royal blood is just a myth.

Comment: @JackBNimble: Okay, I got it. I edited my question. But you're right, it is a myth. However, the people believe it as fact.

Comment: This seems like one of those classic "power of faith in yourself"-type literary devices.

Comment: @GorchestopherH I've added the full quote. It is indeed the belief in yourself, but also, that others must believe.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually, anyone can use the Sword. The problem is that you would have to convince 3 different parties that it works to make it work: the user of the sword, the one it is being used against, and everyone else.

As it was given to the king, it was not long before it was ingrained in legend by the people that only the king and his bloodline could use it. Not only the people believed this, but those who were afraid of the sword did to. If they knew anyone other than the bloodline was using the sword it wouldn't work as anything other than a regular sword because they wouldn't believe that someone not relate to Jerle could bring out the truth telling properties.

> Don't forget that the user of the sword also has to have complete faith in its use. During the book he constantly uses it as a regular sword instead of its intended use due to his warrior training. As you see at the end of *the Sword of Shannara*, Jerle stops believing in it and ultimately fails in his quest because he reverts back to just thinking of it as a sword.

Almost all of the most powerful artifacts in Terry Brooks' world can be used by anyone, even though the legends in the world say it is impossible for others. For example, the elfstones can be used by non-elves, they just have to try harder.

TL;DR The sword is just a sword unless EVERYONE, including the user, believes in it and the user.

Comment: Either "the user and the target", or "everyone". Specifiying separately those groups doesn't make much sense. BTW "everyone" doesn't make much sense anyway: if any single person in the whole world doesn't believe it, it doesn't work? srsly?

Comment: fwiw, the elfstones have their own rules (have to be given as a gift), which comes up more than once.  "magic has odd rules" is a better interpretation than "anyone can use it."

Comment: +1 for the answer about the sword, but I disagree that the Elfstones truly can be used by anyone.  Wil was able to use them with more effort, but he did have elf blood.  And, even so, there were some side-effects of his using them via "try harder", *despite* the fact that he was, in fact, partially of elf blood.  I do not believe that they were actually used anywhere in the series by someone completely non-elf.

Answer (score 0):

The target does not have to *believe* it. If the target is capable of reasoning the truth, the magic of the Sword destroys all its defensive lies and, ultimately, the target. But it is powered by the wielder's acceptance of truth about oneself. Jerle Shannara did not completely accept the truth, shutting off the sword's power in the end.