# How could this person use the Sword of Shannara?

Tags: shannara

So, a while back I asked the question ["Why can only a person of the bloodline of Shannara use the sword?"](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/41008/why-can-only-a-person-of-the-bloodline-of-shannara-use-the-sword) Now, I haven't planned on accepting the answer until I'd finished the series. Well, I just finished the *Heritage* series, and I'm confused.

> Coll was able to use the Sword. Now, if the answer is to be accepted, why could he use it? He doesn't believe he could. Matter of fact, he'd never had any kind of clue that he could, especially since Allanon didn't charge him with retrieving it.

Comment: I want to say, because he was open enough to the possibility and that was enough for the magic to at least start up, as most of the Ohmsfords over the eras don't really believe they can use it either.  The magic reacts more strongly and shuts down with people who don't want to face themselves.  I don't really remember how it reads though, so I will leave this as comment.

Answer (score 3):

Because:

1. > Coll Ohmsford was a Shannara descendant.
2. He did not believe in the sword's magic at first, but the magic convinced him he is ok using it. It is not clear from the book whether he or Par have invoked it for the first time, but once ignited, the magic took hold and he embraced it
3. He accepted the truth it revealed.
4. He was eager to reveal more truth to help his brother: first, to learn the not-so-easy truth about himself and his magic, and second, about the nature of the Shadowen thing locked in the Southwatch. Determination is important when dealing with magic in the world of Shannara.

Comment: @Dave Johnson: the fact you have marked as spoiler is clearly revealed in the first book, as Coll is Par's brother and cannot be anything else. I do not think it is a spoiler.

Comment: It doesn't hurt to mask it just in case, especially considering there a a couple dozen Shanara books. You never know where someone is going to pick it up.